# What happen if I make spark driver crash. Would executors be clear?

Tags: apache-spark

Suppose that I have a running spark driver in client mode. If I command 'kill -9 xxx' and xxx is process number of the driver, what will happen? 
Would executors and workers which are assigned to the driver be collected. If did and how?

Answer (score 1):

The spark-submit script provides the most straightforward way to submit a compiled Spark application to the cluster. For standalone clusters, Spark currently supports two deploy modes. In client mode, the driver is launched in the same process as the client that submits the application. In cluster mode, however, the driver is launched from one of the Worker processes inside the cluster, and the client process exits as soon as it fulfills its responsibility of submitting the application without waiting for the application to finish.

If your application is launched through Spark submit, then the application jar is automatically distributed to all worker nodes. f you wish to kill an application, you may do so through:

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <master url> <driver ID>
```

You can find the driver ID through the standalone Master web UI at http://:8080.

The Spark batch application state and the driver state are coordinated, and communicate with the Spark master together through each Spark batch application process. If you directly issue the OS-level kill command when the driver is in the RUNNING state, the application and driver processes are terminated immediately without communicating with the Spark master. The application state is then FINISHED and the driver state is FAILED.

Killing the driver will cause YARN to restart it, in `yarn-cluster` mode. You want to kill the spark-submit process.